# How to migrate numbers from CSV file to Redshift using AWS DMS?

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

I'm trying to migrate a CSV file from S3 to Redshift using AWS DMS.
One of my columns in the CSV holds integer number. In the JSON mapping file for the S3 endpoint I gave the column a numeric type (I tried several types) but from some reason the column is stored with only zeros in it.
When I give the column a STRING type, I can see the correct numbers in string form in Redshift, but it makes it hard to work with the data warehouse.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Side-question: Since the data is already in S3, why are you wanting to use DMS instead of a normal Redshift `COPY` command?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your CSV file and the configuration you are using to load the data? You could create a 1-line CSV for experimentation to try and get the formatting working -- cut it down to the minimum necessary to try and get it working correctly.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The CSV file is created by my CI system and I don't want to give external access to data warehouse.

Comment: `2018-09-06 12:31:26.356000,5b8e5414a5751f2b853f223e,5b86bb52e5b965aab8f23037,test123,tester,5b83b645f71d2e1611105154,global,test,5b83b6b1f71d2e7ac3105155,single_choice,"testing.",['5b8961619042353d58021aec'],['Mostly true'],5

`
This is a line from the CSV file